# Numerically Stable Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow has been used to compute images but I want to use Tensorflow to compute Biological Models. However, the biological model requires big division and this causes numerical instability. I want to have TensorFlow that supports more numerically stability. Are there any hacks to allow Tensorflow to be more numerically stable? I will follow up with more codes in the near feature but if there are any options please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below paper on Tensorflow Distributions and see if it helps answer your question.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10604.pdf

If not, please elaborate your issue.

Mention any code snippet of what you have tried, or any limitations you faced while implementing your model.